# Unable to update the SQL User login password with variables (Microsoft SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update the SQL user password with the variable passed using my API.

I know the syntax for updating user password is:

```
ALTER USER API_READER WITH PASSWORD='<insert password>';
```

But when I try to do the following it does not work for me

```
ALTER USER API_READER WITH PASSWORD=@read_key
```

it gives me a syntax error.

Should I change the query syntax?

Comment: You can't parametrise the `ALTER USER` statement.

Comment: `ALTER USER ... WITH PASSWORD` is only for contained databases. You need to use `ALTER LOGIN` to change the password used to login to the server

Comment: Can YOU debug code that generates an error without seeing any error message?

Comment: Because my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194912/unable-to-update-the-sql-user-login-password-with-variables-microsoft-sql#comment120525121_68194912) also applied to `ALTER LOGIN`.

Comment: even ALTER LOGIN doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as pointed out by [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194912/unable-to-update-the-sql-user-login-password-with-variables-microsoft-sql#comment120525256_68194912) the `ALTER USER` command alters a `USER` (surprise!) which are **Database** objects. As such these normally don't have a `PASSWORD` property unless you are using a contained database.

Next, as I mentioned, you can't parametrise a call to `ALTER LOGIN` or `ALTER USER`. Per the documentation, the syntax is:

```
 <set_option> ::=
    PASSWORD = 'password' | hashed_password HASHED
```

Notice that is doesn't give `@variable` as an option.

As a result what you need to use dynamic SQL, and inject the new password into the dynamic statement. This would look like the following:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'ALTER LOGIN API_READER WITH PASSWORD = N' + QUOTENAME(@Password,'''') + N';';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks Man .... it works for with the changes you have mentioned :)

Comment: Aside: More generally, the syntax would allow some variation on [`expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), e.g. the syntax for [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax).